# Cannot insert checkbox value into database

Tags: php, mysql, css, xampp, dreamweaver

Hello i'm a newbie in PHP language. So I hope u guys can be simple with me. I need to create like a attendance system for a meeting. Now I was stuck at one part. I need to add a staff from a department for every created meeting event. The staff name was already appear when I click from dropdown menu for every department that retrieve from database. Now I tried to select from the checkbox staff that I want to add with the meeting id. But nothing is happened when I click the submit button after checked the staff name. I want to add to a new table with the meeting id. display.php is code I create to appear the staffname and to check the checkbox and retrieve the record from user table . The checkbox.php is for insert the checked checkbox to a table meetingstaff. Please anyone help me..

Here I attached my PHP code

display.php

```
<label>Reference No:</label>
<label id="attach"><?php echo $_GET["refno"]; ?></label>
<form action="display.php?refno=<?php echo $_GET["refno"]; ?>" method="post">
     <?php do { ?>
        <form action="checkbox.php?refno=<?php echo $_GET["refno"]; ?>" method="post">
        <tr >
        <td><div align="center"><input name="chkl[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="<?   echo $row_Recordset4['staffname']; ?>"></td>
        <td><div align="center"><?php echo $row_Recordset4['staffname']; ?></div></td>
        <td><div align="center"><?php echo $row_Recordset4['staffno']; ?></div></td>
        </div></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } while ($row_Recordset4 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset4));?>
```

checkbox.php

```
<label>Reference No:</label>
<label id="attach"><?php echo $_GET["refno"]; ?></label>
<?php
$checkbox1 = $_POST['chkl'];
if($_POST["Submit"]=="Submit")
{
for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($checkbox1);$i++) {
$query="INSERT INTO meetingstaff (staffname, staffno) VALUES ('".$checkbox1[$i]."')";
mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
}
echo "Record is inserted";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to INSERT a second parameter, or remove `, staffno` from the first part of the INSERT statement. You are passing just one value, but instructing for two columns.

So change your:

`INSERT INTO meetingstaff (staffname, staffno) VALUES ('".$checkbox1[$i]."')`

to either

`INSERT INTO meetingstaff (staffname) VALUES ('".$checkbox1[$i]."')`

or perhaps

`INSERT INTO meetingstaff (staffname, staffno) VALUES ('".$checkbox1[$i]."', ".$i.")`